# pandas.Dataframe.loc[index] How does this work?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

[image]
This is my data. After that I did this:

[image]

This is my train_set.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 16512 entries, 17606 to 15775
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------              --------------  -----   
 0   longitude           16512 non-null  float64 
 1   latitude            16512 non-null  float64 
 2   housing_median_age  16512 non-null  float64 
 3   total_rooms         16512 non-null  float64 
 4   total_bedrooms      16354 non-null  float64 
 5   population          16512 non-null  float64 
 6   households          16512 non-null  float64 
 7   median_income       16512 non-null  float64 
 8   median_house_value  16512 non-null  float64 
 9   ocean_proximity     16512 non-null  object  
 10  income_cat          16512 non-null  category
dtypes: category(1), float64(9), object(1)
```

My doubt is in this part:

```
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42);

for train_index, test_index in split.split(data, data['income_cat']):
  train_set = data.loc[train_index]
  test_set = data.loc[test_index]
```

I wonder how the `train_set` has 16512 entries when we are assigning a different value each time the loop runs. I have read the documentation of `pandas.DataFrame.loc`, it says that `.loc` is used with labels. But looks like `split.split(data, data['income_cat'])` is returning index(s). So my question is what does `split.split(data, data['income_cat'])` return?

Comment: It does not. What makes you think it does?

Comment: It shouldn't do that, please provide data samples for better clarity.